# Using protocol's associated type in generic functions

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to write a simple MVP pattern to follow in my app, so I've written two porotocols to define View Controller and Presenters:

```
protocol PresenterType: class {
    associatedtype ViewController: ViewControllerType

    var viewController: ViewController? { get set }

    func bind(viewController: ViewController?)
}

protocol ViewControllerType: class {
    associatedtype Presenter: PresenterType

    var presenter: Presenter { get }

    init(presenter: Presenter)
}
```

After having those defined I started writing some `RootViewController` and `RootViewPresenter`. The latter looks like:

```
protocol RootViewControllerType: ViewControllerType {
}

final class RootPresenter<VC: RootViewControllerType>: PresenterType {
    weak var viewController: VC?

    func bind(viewController: VC?) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
}
```

Up to this point everything complies and is *fine*, but when I start implementing View Controller like this:

```
protocol RootPresenterType: PresenterType {
}

final class RootViewController<P: RootPresenterType>: UIViewController, ViewControllerType {
    let presenter: P

    init(presenter: Presenter) {
        self.presenter = presenter
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter.bind(viewController: self)
    }
}
```

Immediately I get the following error message:

> Cannot convert value of type 'RootViewController
>
> ' to expected argument type '_?'

I know that `protocol`s with associated types can introduce some limitations, but this example is pretty straightforward and I can't make it work. Is it possible to achieve something that I want, or do I have to look for some other, less Swifty pattern?

Comment: I am not sure if two protocols can use eachother if they both have associated types

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you're trying to achieve is possible due to the circular dependency between the respective associated types of the `PresenterType` and `ViewControllerType` protocols.

Consider for a moment if the suspect code above *did* compile ... how would you go about instantiating either the `RootPresenter` or `RootViewController` classes?  Because both depend on one another, you'll end up with errors like the following:

[image: Generic parameter error 1.]
[image: Generic parameter error 2.]

As you can see, the compiler can't fully resolve the generic parameters due to the associated types.

I think your best bet is to remove the associated type from one or both of the protocols.  For example, removing the associated type from the `PresenterType` protocol and updating the `RootPresenter` class breaks the circular dependency and allows your code to compile normally.

```
protocol PresenterType: class {
    var viewController: UIViewController? { get set }

    func bind(viewController: UIViewController?)
}

final class RootPresenter: PresenterType {
    weak var viewController: UIViewController?

    func bind(viewController: UIViewController?) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
}
```